# Difference between cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ and cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

What is the difference between `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_` and `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_` in SQL server?

Much appreciated if I could get some help.

Answer (score 13):

The documentation seems to give a pretty clear explanation right away. (I've added emphasis to both where relevant.)

[cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx):

> Returns one row for each change applied to the source table within the specified log sequence number (LSN) range. ***If a source row had multiple changes during the interval, each change is represented in the returned result set.*** ...

[cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522511.aspx):

> Returns one net change row for each source row changed within the specified LSN range. ***That is, when a source row has multiple changes during the LSN range, a single row that reflects the final content of the row is returned by the function.*** ...

That is, `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_` would return multiple result rows (i.e., *all changes*) for a single source row if it had multiple changes, whereas `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_` will only ever return one result row for a single source row (i.e., the *net change*), regardless of how many changes occurred to that source row during the interval.

Comment: Plus one for RTFM and a link to TFM